# How to access Redis Cluster via Single Endpoint

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I have created a redis cluster which comprrises of 3 masters and 3 slaves. Now, i need to connect the redis cluster to application using an endpoint like redis URI.
for stand alone redis, we have  redisURI=redis://:password@192.168.1.1:6379
I need a similar type of single endpoint for my cluster which can automatically redirect incase of failovers.

Actually I have no idea about the cluster endpoint, till now i have only used stand alone redis node.